# How to read txt as dataframe without symbols

Tags: python, pandas

I got txt file contains:

> [['img_index', 'cent_x', 'cent_y', 's_hum / 12', 'is_skin'], ['1',
>   1437, 520, 36, 4], ['2', 1363, 488, 36, -1]]

how to open it in pd.Dataframe wwithout '[]'

```
df = pd.read_csv(txt_file)
```

I got

[image]

help to get rid of

> ]  [  '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can generate a normal csv:

`with open('your_text.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().replace('], [', '\n').replace('[','').replace(']','').replace("'",'')
data_file = open("data.csv", "w")
_ = data_file.write(data)
data_file.close()`

Answer (score 4):

You will need to format this file before read with pandas.

---

```
import pandas as pd


def transform_csv(line):
    line = line.replace('[', '')
    line = line.replace(']]', '')
    line = line.replace('], ', '\n')
    line = line.replace("'", '')
    return line


with open("txt_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    with open("out.txt", "w") as f_out:
        for line in f_in:
            line = transform_csv(line)
            f_out.write(line)
        f_out.close()
    f_in.close()


df = pd.read_csv('out.txt')
print(df)
```

---

output:

[image]